# Scatter Plot error: x and y must be the same size

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, linear-regression, scatter-plot

I was working on linear regression by using sklearn.
This is the data:

```
Name    Symbol  Date    High    Low Open    Close   Volume  Marketcap
SNo                                 
2709    Bitcoin BTC 2020-09-27 23:59:59 10803.976080    10622.921758    10746.892758    10775.269376    5.374597e+10    1.993580e+11
2710    Bitcoin BTC 2020-09-28 23:59:59 10945.347907    10703.893251    10776.613639    10709.652182    4.776239e+10    1.981541e+11
2711    Bitcoin BTC 2020-09-29 23:59:59 10860.000698    10649.495439    10709.650022    10844.640981    4.658240e+10    2.006601e+11
2712    Bitcoin BTC 2020-09-30 23:59:59 10847.256993    10669.321093    10843.870751    10784.491578    4.417107e+10
```

Here is the code:

```
# Import all the libraries we need for Linear Regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
import math
# Splitting the data into the "attributes" and "labels".
x = df[["High", "Low", "Open", "Volume", "Marketcap"]].values
y = df["Close"].values


# Splitting the data into the training and testing sets.
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

# Train the Algorithm
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)

# Testing the linear regression model
regressor.score(x_test, y_test)

# Predicting the price
y_predicted = regressor.predict(x_test)

# Plot the scatter plot
plt.scatter(x_test, y_test, color='red')
plt.plot(x_test, y_predicted, color='blue', linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

I have followed all the instructions online, however, the result said x and y must be the same size. I am not sure which array I should change or another mistake.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: type len(x) and len(y) in the console. Are they the same? Please provide some data for x and y, as there is no line in this code for setting the value of "df"

Comment: The sequences you are using for the x and y data need to have the same number of points - you need to inspect them and decide which one has too many or too few or which one has the incorrect shape. At this point only you can do that as we don't have access to your data because you haven't provided a [mre], and we don't know which plot statement caused the problem because you didn't provide the whole Traceback.

Comment: `I am not sure ...` during your attempt to solve this problem have you ruled anything out? - do you know which parts are correct?

Comment: I have updated the data.